# Google Analytics measurement protocol authentication?

Tags: authentication, authorization, google-analytics-api

I'm looking at Googles [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide), which gives you a way to send google analytics information from your server. However, there doesn't seem to be any authentication required. Have I missed something? Otherwise, what's to stop other people randomly spamming fake data to my account?

Comment: After 3 years I have the same question... Nobody can answer?

Comment: 6 years ago… still… just to checkin here

Comment: @BogdanSavluk What are you checkin in for? What is unclear?

Answer (score 6):

There is no authentication required. 
There is nothing to stop people randomly spamming your account.

This is what has lead to the 'Ghost Referral' issue.
See Link: 
[image]https://moz.com/blog/stop-ghost-spam-in-google-analytics-with-one-filter

Google Analytics was initially set up the measurement protocol with good will envisaged, however this has not been the case.

Comment: What if I use Measurement Protocol to send data to google analytics? This trick won't work. Is there any method to configre google analytics recieve data only from your server ip or smth?

Comment: What do you mean by "What if I use Measurement Protocol to send data to google analytics? This trick won't work."? There is no method to configure Google Analytics to receive data from only designated servers. The goal of the Measurement Protocol was to "allow  developers to measure how users interact with their business from almost any environment".

Answer (score 0):

The measurement protocol is to make collection of data as simple as possible. Think of it as an arbitrary data sink.

To separate fake data from data generated by sources under your control you can use a property of a hit you report. E.g. by setting a custom metric to some secret. Collected data then can be filtered by that property to exclude possibly "fake" data.